# End of file exception error

Tags: python

I am trying to modify a function to manage end of file exception error. The integer function is supposed to handle the EOFError and print a message and return None to the main(). Then, the main function has to be modified accordingly to handle the None value. I have done the changes but not sure if I am on the right track. Could someone please give me some pointers? Thanks

```
def integer( prompt ):
    value_str = input( prompt )
    try:
        value_int = int( value_str )
    except ValueError:
        print ( "** Invalid input, assuming 0 **" )
        value_int = 0
    except EOFError:
        print("End of file error occurred.")
        return None

    return value_int

def main():
    try:
        numer = integer( "Enter the numerator: " )
        denom = integer( "Enter the denominator: " )
        print( numer, "divided by", denom, end=" " )
        result = numer/denom
        print( "yields", result )

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print( "** Invalid: attempted to divide by zero **" )
    except EOFError:
        print("unsupported operand type (s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'")

    print( "Program halted" )

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input statement is outside the try block. Move it inside the block & you should be good to go

```
def integer( prompt ):
    try:
        value_str = input( prompt )
...
```

Comment: No, that's not the only problem. If one of the numbers is None, it will raise a TypeError, not an EOFError

Comment: I think, once the integer function finds the error, it is not sending the None value to the main function.

Comment: The question was about EOF exception handling right? I assume there are a wealth of 'other' exceptions that also could be checked for KeyboardInterrupt comes to mind). Since the OP asked about EOF, I focused there.

Comment: The program should handle EOF inside function integer. That function should display a message and return the value None when the user signals end of file. Then, the main function should respond appropriately when function integer returns None.

Comment: Refer to the answer -- I believe it's what you want.

Comment: After I changed the program as you said, the output is giving me a type error. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType' So, should I then put another exception to address the type error?

Comment: Yup.  As I said, I focused specifically on the subject of the OP. Making a complete program is left up to the author.